# What is a hotplug event from the interface?

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface

According to Debian *Network setup* document `allow-hotplug <interface_name>` stanza in `/etc/network/interfaces` file starts an interface when the kernel detects a hotplug event from the interface. What is this hotplug event?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`allow-hotplug <interface>`, is used the same way `auto` is by most people. However, the hotplug event is something that involves kernel/udev detection against the hardware, that could be a cable being connected to the port, or a USB-to-Ethernet dongle that will be up and running whenever you plug on USB, or either a PCMCIA wireless card being connected to the slot.

My personal opinion: I also think that `allow-hotplug` could have more documented examples to make this thing easier to understand. As pointed out by other U&L members and Debian lists, those two options create the "chicken and egg problem" when there are no cables connected or when an event is created:

- [Re: network reference v2: questions about allow-hotplug](https://lists.debian.org/debian-doc/2008/02/msg00010.html)
- [Re: Netcfg and allow-hotplug vs auto](https://lists.debian.org/debian-boot/2007/07/msg00377.html)

**References:**

- [Good detailed explanation of /etc/network/interfaces syntax?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128439/34720);
- [Re: Netcfg and allow-hotplug vs auto](https://lists.debian.org/debian-boot/2007/07/msg00375.html);
- Howto Set Up Multiple Network Schemes on a Linux Laptop [PCMCIA, Cardbus, USB](http://www.shallowsky.com/linux/networkSchemes.html#hotpluggable) ;
- Debian networking. [Basic sintax of /etc/networ/interfaces](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_basic_syntax_of_etc_network_interfaces);

Comment: I see. However, in case of servers, the best practice is probably to use `auto` which will force the interface up regardless whether the cable is connected etc?

Comment: Depens. I had a case where i have to set to `allow-hotplug` because i wanted to ensure that my firewall would negotiate link AFTER the core switch totally booted and applied it's confiurations. In general cases, `auto` should be enough.

Comment: I would also point out that, in most cases, cloud/EC2/VPS/VMs should use `auto`! I've lost networking with a `nohup service networking restart` before with `allow-hotplug`.

Comment: Good catch. I found some of the same issues you and the other answer by Sprinterfreak pointed out at Debian Lists. Edited my answer with this valuable information

Comment: Incorrect. "If I power up a system with a built-in ethernet interface, but with no ethernet cable plugged into it, does plugging in an ethernet cable also generate a hotplug event that is noticed by allow-hotplug? Unfortunately no". / https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/detect-wired-connection-with-udev-606568/#post2989660 / https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/520633/29483

Comment: So if you insert a lan cable to the port `allow-hotplug` will see it and blink. `auto` will maybe not?

Answer (score 9):

There is a general important thing to remember:

If you configured a plugable device as `auto`, it will prevent the entire system from booting if it doesn't exist at the moment!
Whether an `allow-hotplug` configured device **IS NOT** set to up after services networking restart automatically. That's totally confusing. In both cases I've lost entire systems.
If you have to restart neworking being connected to a hotplug-device you **MUST** manually ensure to `ifup <interface>` after restart like this

`services networking restart; ifup wlan0`

at once. Otherwise you are screwed.

Comment: "...device as `auto`, it will prevent the entire system from booting if it doesn't exist at the moment", I just tried this on virtual machine and it booted alright (without network of course, since I disabled in VM software all network adapters), care to explain more?