# Boot blocked during 1min30sec because /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, wifi, systemd, ethernet

With the following config (see config file below):

1. if **only ethernet cable** is connected, it 100% works: I can quickly SSH the computer via eth0's IP,
2. if **both ethernet cable and wifi dongle** are connected, it 100% works: I can quickly SSH the computer via eth0's IP  or wlan0's IP,
3. if **only wifi dongle** is connected, I have to wait 1min30sec after boot to be able to SSH the computer! *It's like the fact no ethernet cable is there "blocks"* the boot* during 1min30sec.

**Why does the fact no ethernet cable is present in case #3 block the boot for 1min30sec?**

This is confirmed by:

```
# systemd-analyze blame
  1min 28.442s networking.service
         353ms getty-static.service
```

---

## /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "<myssid>"
wpa-psk "<mypasswd>"
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "myssid"
wpa-psk "mypasswd"
```

The differences between `auto` and `allow-hotplug` are explained well in [Good detailed explanation of `/etc/network/interfaces` syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128662/59989):

> `auto interface` – Start the interface(s) at boot.
>   That’s why the `lo` interface uses this kind of linking configuration.
>
> `allow-hotplug interface` – Start the interface
>   when a "hotplug" event is detected.
>   In the real world, this is used in the same situations as `auto` but
>   the difference is that it will wait for an event like "being detected by
>   udev hotplug api" or "cable linked".