# What exactly do the /etc/network/interfaces 'up' and 'down' stanzas do?

Tags: networking, network-interface

I am concerned that I may be incorrectly using the `up` and `down` interface options in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I was under the impression that these options were simply executed as a 'hook' after bringing the interface up or after taking it down.

However, reading [a really good answer on SEU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128439/good-detailed-explanation-of-etc-network-interfaces-syntax), I am now uncertain of what these options are really there for.

The manpage is not a great source of enlightenment either. I have read the manpage and think that I can pretty much put any command into the `up` or `down` option hooks but I would appreciate someone else to verify that.

### Question

Would the following configuration be ok for an interface, specifically the `up` and `down` parts? Or is this interpretation wrong and prone to unexpected results?

```
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.100.1
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 192.168.100.254
up ring_a_bell
down send_an_email
```

Where the `ring_a_bell` and the `send_an_email` just refer to any valid system command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you link to is right about a great many things, but it is wrong about what `up` and `down` do. You can, indeed, use `up` and `down` in very much the way you post here. They are alternatives for `post-up` and `post-down`, if that makes it clearer.

However, it *is* possible to use `up` and `down` as replacements for configuring the interface, provided there is no other configuration on the interface; i.e., if you have something like

```
iface ethX inet manual
```

then you can use `up` and `down` to semi-manually configure the interface (instead of having the standard `address` and `netmask` and `gateway` and friends there).