# How can I bridge two interfaces with ip/iproute2?

Tags: networking, ip, network-interface, bridge, iproute

I know how to create a bridge using `brctl`, but I have been advised not to use this anymore, and to use `iproute2` or `ip` instead(since `brctl` is deprecated presumably). Assuming this is good advice, how do I create a bridge using `ip`? For instance, say I wanted to bridge `eth0` and `eth1`.

Comment: Look at the archwiki page https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use the `bridge` object ip  the `ip` command, or the `bridge` command that makes part of the `iproute2` package.

## Basic link manipulation

To create a bridge named `br0`, that have `eth0` and `eth1` as members:

```
ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip link set dev br0 up
ip link set dev eth0 master br0
ip link set dev eth1 master br0
```

To remove an interface from the bridge:

```
ip link set dev eth0 nomaster
```

And finally, to destroy a bridge after no interface is member:

```
ip link del br0
```

## Forwarding manipulation

To manipulate other aspects of the bridge like the FDB([Forwarding Database](http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/linux_net/0596002556/understandlni-CHP-16-SECT-13.html)) I suggest you to take a look at the `bridge(8)` [command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/bridge.8.html). Examples:

Show forwarding database on `br0`

```
bridge fdb show dev br0
```

Disable a port(`eth0`) from processing [BPDUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_Protocol_Data_Unit). This will make the interface filter any incoming bpdu

```
bridge link set dev eth0 guard on
```

Setting [STP Cost](http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/sep/5/spanning-tree-port-costs/) to a port(`eth1` for example):

```
bridge link set dev eth1 cost 4
```

To set root guard on eth1:

```
bridge link set dev eth1 root_block on
```

Cost is calculated using some factors, and the link speed is one of them. Using a fix cost and disabling the processing of BPDUs and enabling root_block is somehow simmilar to a `guard-root` feature from switches.

Other features like vepa, veb and [hairpin](https://lwn.net/Articles/347344/) mode can be found on `bridge link` sub-command list.

## VLAN rules manipulation

The `vlan` object from the bridge command will allow you to create ingress/egress filters on bridges.

To show if there is any vlan ingress/egress filters:

```
bridge vlan show
```

To add rules to a given interface:

```
bridge vlan add dev eth1 <vid, pvid, untagged, self, master>
```

To remove rules. Use the same parameters as `vlan add` at the end of the command to delete a specific rule.

```
bridge vlan delete dev eth1
```

**Related stuff:**

- [bridge(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/bridge.8.html) manpage
- [How to create a bridge interface](http://baturin.org/docs/iproute2/#Create%20a%20bridge%20interface)

Comment: There are a couple bridge parameters you can't set with the `bridge` util, e.g. `ip link set br0 type bridge stp_state 1`, can see more with `ip link help bridge`

Comment: I am trying to do the same on current Ubuntu 22.04 - but I still cannot ping hosts on ther sides of the bridge. Has anything changed since 2016?..

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent of `brctl show` is `bridge link`.
You can show the bridge status per device with `bridge link show dev eth0` but `bridge` looks at the network interface and tells you which bridge it belongs to - not which network interfaces belong to a certain bridge.

There doesn't seem to be a equivalent to `brctl show br0`.
You could get something similar by using grep, though:

```
ip link | grep "master br0"
```

Answer (score -1):

As I'm point-low unable to comment on Dominik's post and contribute, today we have that command right there. It's:

```
ip link show master <bridge name>
```

HTH.

PS: Also discover beauty of "group" config. element to manipulate link group of interest.