# How does the following network configuration differ on eth0?

Tags: network-interface, interface

I have a raspberry pi and it has 2 configuration files in `/etc/network/`, although I set it up I'm very new to networking and not sure what each of the lines do or what the differences are between the two files, particularly with regards to `eth0`. The "active" file is copied as `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I read through [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128439/good-detailed-explanation-of-etc-network-interfaces-syntax) question but I have the following question:

With config 1 and the ethernet cable connected to the internet what is the expected behaviour? Also using config 1 is there any reason a windows computer shouldn't be able to connect to the ad hoc network?

Configuration 1:

The raspberry should create an ad hoc wifi network that someone can connect to.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-channel 1
    wireless-essid RPiwireless
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

Configuration 2:

The raspberry pi will connect to the internet if it has the correct settings in the wpa file or if an ethernet cable is connected to it.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```