# Interface creation via iproute2 resulted to "Cannot find device" error

Tags: networking, network-interface, iproute

I'm trying to create additional interface with preconfigured static IP.

So I added configuration into `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth88
iface eth88 inet static
   address 10.10.0.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
```

And trying to up it with:

```
ip link set dev eth88 up
```

As a result I've got: "Cannot find device eth88"

In some articles I've read that interfaces represent physical devices (nic?). But I have some docker0 interface created by docker. Should I create somewhere virtual device to enable my interface?

Comment: A good explanation can be found here:
<br>
<https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128439/good-detailed-explanation-of-etc-network-interfaces-syntax#128662>

Comment: The first thing to understand is that _that is not_ Linux network interfaces.  That is Debian's `interfaces` system, which not all Linux operating systems share.  So this question is not tagged or titled appropriately.  Do you want to know about Debian's system, which it even tries to make work on the FreeBSD and Hurd kernels?  Or about network interfaces at a basic level that is common to all Linux operating systems but not necessarily other kernels?  Please fix your question as appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A network interface is always backed by some kernel module or similar part of the kernel that represents *something*, be it a physical interface, or some virtual interface that in some way talks to other interfaces. There are also `dummy` interface that don't do anything; you can assign an IP address to them, but it very likely won't do what you want to achieve.

In general, you can add new interfaces with a variant of `ip link add ... type ...`. See `man ip-link` for details and a list of types.

You can also add several IP addresses to a single interface. With `ip`, you don't need the `eth0:1` etc. of `ifconfig` anymore.

I suspect this is an [XY-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), if you would tell us what you actually want to achieve, and what you need the second IP address for, it will be easier to answer.