# How to disable login prompt on Debian 11 so that I can connect over SSH instead of setting up auto-login?

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, networking

I have setup a Debian 11 headless server in my local network. I want to connect to this box over SSH, but every time it boots up, it gets stuck in a login prompt, and I won't be able to SSH into this until I physically connect keyboard to this server and login.

The server won't establish Ethernet connectivity until I physically login to this server. Only after I physically login, this connects to Ethernet, and then I can SSH from other devices. This creates a problem, since anybody can connect a keyboard and a monitor to this server and access my data since auto-login is setup.

What is the appropriate way to setup or mitigate this behavior?

Edit-0:
**tl;dr** : I want to disable tty login prompt on startup and only allow ssh login. I have no reason to have a tty since I want this to be completely headless.

Edit-1: I have fixed the issue and decided to keep the TTY login prompt so that it can be of help during an emergency

Comment: What you need to do is find out why the interactive login is needed in the first place.  I can see several possibilities.  It could be an "decrypt my disk" prompt.  It could be a "disk needs fsck"  It could be something overenginered to be a desktop.  Are there any more details you can tell us?

Comment: Ditto. It should be totally possible to start networking and an SSH server before anyone logs in locally. Frankly I would call this setup *standard*.

Comment: @DavidG. As soon as I start my Debian box, it boots up to a login prompt, just asking for my username and password. It does not show anything else. I had installed my Debian 11 with a desktop environment (xfce), and then I disabled it since I realized I did not require it. I guess when I installed with a DE, it was setup as a Desktop. I don't need any TTY login prompt at all. All I want is, as soon as the server boots up, it connects to Ethernet, starts SSH server, and waits until I login over SSH. Is it possible?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I disabled xfce desktop environment because I later realized I don't need it anymore, and only require SSH login, and since there's no DE, it shows the login prompt. I don't want any TTY login, but only require SSH login. Is it possible to modify this behavior?

Comment: OK. Suggestions:  Uninstall XFCE if you haven't done so already, along with various X components.  Similarly "network-manager".  Similarly any optional "systemd" components.  Then ensure your network is properly configured, and "auto" in "/etc/network/interfaces" or "/etc/network/interfaces.d/*".  I believe network-manager and systemd are where the "overengineering" lives.

Comment: You haven't noted if this is a command line or graphic login prompt...  If the later, yes, kill it (uninstalling X should do it, and save disk space too).  If the former, it is a useful emergency capability and of minimal cost, but could still be killed.  It is a configuration item in your init or systemd.  With systemd I can't help, but for init/sysvinit it would be an entry in /etc/inittab.

Comment: @DavidG. I have disabled the graphical login, and now left with command line login prompt. But I have decided to keep the command line login, after I realized from your comment that it could be of use during an emergency, such as if the network goes down, or a fault SSH config, I can hook a keyboard and fix it. I will leave the command prompt login as it is, thank you!

Comment: Does this solve the problem of not being able to remote login until you locally login, or is that still an issue?

Comment: @DavidG. Yes, finally fixed it an hour ago. The core issue was that my server was not establishing Ethernet connectivity until I logged into the box physically. So after I added "allow-hotplug enp1s0" in my /etc/network/interfaces, I no longer have that issue. I can now login to my box over SSH. I no longer have to plug keyboard/display to my box physically just so that it establishes Ethernet connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the issue. I edited the `/etc/network/interfaces` and added `"allow-hotplug enp1s0"` line.
Now my Debian box will establish Ethernet connectivity (local network) on startup without my intervention, and once the connectivity is established, I can login over SSH.

Initially I tried with "auto" but it did not work (not sure why, I need to understand more about this), then I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128662/230224) answer.

I have decided to keep the login prompt in the box as it is, so that it can be of help during an emergency, such as if the network goes down.